# Images saved from Camera preview on landscape

Tags: java, android, bitmap, camera, rotation

I'm working on my first Android app. It is using a camera preview from the camera1 api (I know it's deprecated but I can't find easy to understand resources for camera2).

The app is much harder and is above my level since the camera API isn't easy to use. But I'm mostly there.

The problem I have is that my Camera preview always saves pictures on landscape mode, regardless of orientation. I've looked this up and had a lot of troubles implementing Exifinterfaces, matrices and bitmaps.

Here's the code I'm currently using.

```
public static File getPictureFile(int mediaType) {

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Camera App");
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("Camera App", "Failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;

    if (mediaType == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}

public void takePicturePreview() {
    Camera.PictureCallback mPicture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getPictureFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (pictureFile ==null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
                return;
            }

            //ROTATION NEEDS TO OCCUR HERE
            //String filePath = pictureFile.getPath();
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);


            /*ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/

            //int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
            //Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            //matrix.postRotate(orientation);

            //bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,85,fos);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };



    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);

}
```

Everything in comments is test code that I've tried to use but nothing is working. So I've tried to use BitmapFactory, Exifinterface to get orientation, then matrix to rotate it and then creating and saving the bitmap but it just crashes.

At this point, the whole exifinteraces, bitmaps are so unclear to me it's really hard to understand what's going on.

Can anyone please give any hints or help to allow my app to save photos in the correct orientation?

Answer (score 0):

If using the old camera API, you need to call [Parameters.setRotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int)) and Camera.setParameters() before calling Camera.takePicture().

The documentation includes sample code on how to get the current device orientation.